# python check if a string contains a 'word' with a certain format

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to check if a string contains a word with a certain format- 3numbers+ x+ 3numbers. I'm working with a pandas dataframe and the data looks like this:

```
|            ad name             |
| puma sneaker ad banner 320x480 |
| puma mobile 320x240 video ad   |
```

the 320x480 and 320x240 indicate the size of the ad banner and I want to create a new column that only contains the size

```
|            ad name             |  banner size  |
| puma sneaker ad banner 320x480 |   320x480     |
| puma mobile 320x240 video ad   |   320x240     |
```

For Example in sentence 'puma sneaker ad banner **320x480**', I want to be able to print out '**320x480**', and in sentence 'puma mobile **320x240** video ad', I want to be able to print '**320x240**'.
I am not familiar with Regex and don't even know if this is achievable with it.
To brute force it I can do an if-else statement:

```
if "320x240" in somestring: 
    print "320x240"
elif "320x480" in somestring:
    print "320x480"
...
```

But I don't want to brute force it, I'd like to find another way around to make the code cleaner. Any advice?

Comment: Are you working with a pandas dataframe? You should include some sample data **in dataframe form** and expected output.

Comment: Is `x` the value to look for? Or can you make a list of items (e.g. `L = ['320x240','320x480']` and iterate over it in a for loop.

Comment: the regexp for `3numbers+ x+ 3numbers` is r`\d{3}x\d{3}`, you may use `re.findall`

Comment: @QuangHoang yes I am working with pandas dataframe, I have updated by post. Thanks

Comment: @anvoice x here only serves as a single char, i'm looking to extract the whole '320x240', please see my updated post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for pandas:

```
df['banner size'] = df['ad name'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}x\d{3})')
```

if you have more than one banner size in row, use `str.findall` instead.

---

```
import re
if re.search(r'\d{3}x\d{3}', somestring):
    output = re.findall(r'\d{3}x\d{3}', somestring)
    print(', '.join(output))
else:
    print('Nothing find')
```